# Automatically change an attribute based on another attribute

Tags: magento-enterprise, event-observer, product-attribute

I am using an Observer to change an attribute value. The event used is catalog_product_save_before. I don't understand why my attribute is saved after the second save of product.

```
public function changeProductAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
    if(empty($groupPrices)){
        $product->setMembersOnlyPrice(false);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'members_only_price');
    }
    else {
        foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
            if($groupPrice['cust_group'] == 1){
                $product->setMembersOnlyPrice(true);
                $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'members_only_price');
                return $this;
            }
            else {
                $product->setMembersOnlyPrice(false);
                $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'members_only_price');
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. GroupPrice needs to be taken like this:

```
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
    if ($attribute){
        $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
        $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
    }
```

Comment: If you think your solution best answers your question then please accept it so as it doesn't show up as unsolved.